# urlpatterns, как в регулярке включить ленивую выборку

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, django, маршрутизация

Я создаю маршрут такой:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'(?:(?P<slug>.*?)?/)?', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index_url'),
]
```

Нужно, чтобы на этот шаблон ссылался при вызове таких юрлов:

```
/             #Переменная slug=None    
/some-slug/   #Переменная slug='some-slug'  
/some-slug    #Переменная slug='some-slug'
```

Однако, нужно 404 отдавать при таких урлах:

```
/some-slug/321
/some-slug/fdsf/3213/asd/
И т.д.
```

Никак эту регулярку вывести не могу.

Моя в принципе работает, но по какой-то причине она берет все символы после самого паттерна slug.
То есть такая страница `/some-slug/fdsf/3213/asd/` перенаправится на вьюху, но в slug запишется нужное значение. А нужно, чтобы не перенаправлялось.

Comment: Попробуйте `^/(?P<slug>[^/]*)/?$` (или `(?P<slug>[^/]*)/?$`)

Comment: не, не то, не правильно\

Comment: @VostokSisters почему не то?

Comment: Значит, моя регулярка была верной. См. [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/895870/182013)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В регулярном выражении `(?:(?P<slug>.*?)?/)?` не хватает символов `^` и `$`, обозначающих соответственно начало и конец строки. Кроме того, символ `.` находит любой символ, даже `/`, поэтому даже [после добавления `^`/`$`](https://regex101.com/r/ljuXHr/1/) найдётся совпадение в `/some-slug/fdsf/3213/asd/`. Для того, чтобы найти любой символ, кроме `/`, можно использовать исключающий символьный класс `[^/]`.

Используйте

```
r'^(?P<slug>[^/]*)/?$'
```

См. [демо на regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rHAxJS/3).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?P<slug>[^/]*)` - Группа `slug`: ноль и более символов, отличных от `/`
- `/?` - один или ноль символов `/`
- `$` - конец строки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Всё-таки ошибка была с моей стороны. Всё дело в неправильной регулярке.

Путем тестов, используя сайт [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rHAxJS/2/), вывел свою регулярку. Может кому пригодится или просто интересно, вот:

```
r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]*)/?(?!.)'
```